# Format double precision in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, formatting, floating-point

I have a table with 3 columns:

```
  customer_name varchar
 ,account_type varchar
 ,current_balance double precision
```

Example values for current_balance:

```
1200
1500.5
1500
```

I want them to display like this:

```
1200.00
1500.50
1500.00
```

I tried the following query:

```
SELECT to_char(current_balance,'9999999999999999D99')
  FROM bank;
```

It formats the way I want but adds a space at the beginning. How to solve this? Is there a better way to format?

Comment: Stop right where you are.  Carefully [read the section on how doubles are treated in Postgres](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-FLOAT).  Doubles are treated as floating point values.  Floats are stored and calculated in such a way that they can lose precision.  Do not use a floating point value to store a monetary value.  Use the `NUMERIC` or `DECIMAL` types.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`trim`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/functions-string.html) to remove the extra spaces.  With no arguments, it removes only spaces.

```
charles=# SELECT to_char(12345.67,'99999999999999999D99');
        to_char
-----------------------
              12345.67
(1 row)

charles=# SELECT trim(to_char(12345.67,'99999999999999999D99'));
  btrim
----------
 12345.67
(1 row)
```

Comment: hi Charles.. if my input record is 0 (Zero) that time it gives .00 only. but I want 0.00 how can I do this..?

Comment: I don't know, actually.  I'm still learning all the ins and outs of Postgres.  If all else fails, you can try a `CASE` that check to see if the number is zero, and returns '0.00' if so.

Comment: Late to the party, but somebody should probably mention '99...0D99' as a possible solution to the 0.00 requirement.

Answer (score 8):

As already pointed out in a comment, [it's **bad** design to use a floating point type (real, double, float) for a money balance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency).  This will lead you to trouble. Use [`DECIMAL`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-INT) instead.

Comment: Ok thank you... I note your points and here after I will use decimal.

Comment: @ungalnanban: This has to do with rounding errors when you don't use decimal, so you better do, because if the accounting-sums are wrong, any float-to-string-conversion will be your lesser problem...

Answer (score 3):

```
to_char(current_balance, 'FM9999999999999999D99')
```

From [the docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/functions-formatting.html):

> FM: prefix fill mode (suppress padding
>   blanks and zeroes)

If you want a locale-specific currency symbol, try `L`:

```
to_char(current_balance, 'FML9999999999999999D99')
```

> L: currency symbol (uses locale)

Results from PG 8.4 against column called `dbl` with value of 12345.678 where id = 1:

```
>>> import psycopg2
>>> conn = psycopg2.connect(host='localhost', database='scratch', user='',password='')
>>> c = conn.cursor()

>>> c.execute("select to_char(dbl, '9999999999999999D99') from practice where id = 1;")
>>> c.fetchall() # with padding
[('            12345.68',)]

>>> c.execute("select to_char(dbl, 'FM9999999999999999D99') from practice where id = 1;")
>>> c.fetchall() # no padding
[('12345.68',)]

>>> c.execute("select to_char(dbl, 'FML9999999999999999D99') from practice where id = 1;")
>>> c.fetchall() # with locale-specific currency symbol
[('$12345.68',)]
```