# PART 2 - Formate the double precisiont's as 0.00 in postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

> SELECT
>   trim(to_char(123,'9999999999D99'));
>
> 123.00 (1 row)
>
> SELECT
>   trim(to_char(00,'9999999999D99'));
>
> .00 (1 row)

I wrote the above query it giving the result as .00 if the amount is 0 (Zeor)?
I need the output formate as 0.00. how to do this.

[PART -1 Format double precision in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3122808/format-double-precision-in-postgresql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a 0 instead of 9 of:

```
SELECT trim(to_char(00,'999999990D99'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the following:

```
SELECT trim(to_char(00,'9999999990D99'));
```

The `0` sets a leading zero.